# Update single column based on multiple 'priority' columns

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

Suppose you had a DataFrame with a number of columns / Series- say five for example. If the fifth column (named 'Updated Col') had values, in addition to nans, what would be the best way to insert values into 'Updated Col' from other columns in place of the nans based on a preferred column order?

e.g. my dataframe looks something like this;

```
Date                 1     2    3   4   Updated Col
12/03/2017 0:00     0.4                 0.9
12/03/2017 0:10     0.4                 0.1
12/03/2017 0:20     0.4                 0.6
12/03/2017 0:30     0.9   0.7           Nan
12/03/2017 0:40     0.1                 Nan
12/03/2017 0:50     0.6            0.5  Nan
12/03/2017 1:00     0.4        0.3      Nan
12/03/2017 1:10     0.3            0.2  Nan
12/03/2017 1:20     0.9                 0.8
12/03/2017 1:30     0.9                 0.8
12/03/2017 1:40     0.0                 0.9
```

..and say for example I wanted the values from column 3 as a priority, followed by 2, then 1, i would expect the DataFrame to look like this;

```
                  1    2      3   4   Updated Col
12/03/2017 0:00  0.4                  0.9
12/03/2017 0:10  0.4                  0.1
12/03/2017 0:20  0.4                  0.6
12/03/2017 0:30  0.9  0.7             0.7
12/03/2017 0:40  0.1                  0.1
12/03/2017 0:50  0.6             0.5  0.5
12/03/2017 1:00  0.4        0.3       0.3
12/03/2017 1:10  0.3             0.2  0.2
12/03/2017 1:20  0.9                  0.8
12/03/2017 1:30  0.9                  0.8
12/03/2017 1:40  0.0                  0.9
```

..values would be input from the lower priority columns only if the higher priority columns were empty / NaN.

What would be the best way to do this?

I've tried numerous np.where attempts but cant work out what the best way would be?

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: I would try a basic loop through the Updated Col column and replace the nan values with numeric values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`fillna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html) with forward filling (`ffill`) and then select  column:

```
updated_col =  'Updated Col'
#define columns for check, maybe [1,2,3,4] if integer colum names
cols = ['1','2','3','4'] + [updated_col]

print (df[cols].ffill(axis=1))
      1    2    3    4  Updated Col
0   0.4  0.4  0.4  0.4          0.9
1   0.4  0.4  0.4  0.4          0.1
2   0.4  0.4  0.4  0.4          0.6
3   0.9  0.9  0.7  0.7          0.7
4   0.1  0.1  0.1  0.1          0.1
5   0.6  0.6  0.6  0.5          0.5
6   0.4  0.4  0.3  0.3          0.3
7   0.3  0.3  0.3  0.2          0.2
8   0.9  0.9  0.9  0.9          0.8
9   0.9  0.9  0.9  0.9          0.8
10  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0          0.9

df[updated_col] = df[cols].ffill(axis=1)[updated_col]
print (df)
               Date    1   2    3    4  Updated Col
0   12/03/2017 0:00  0.4 NaN  NaN  NaN          0.9
1   12/03/2017 0:10  0.4 NaN  NaN  NaN          0.1
2   12/03/2017 0:20  0.4 NaN  NaN  NaN          0.6
3   12/03/2017 0:30  0.9 NaN  0.7  NaN          0.7
4   12/03/2017 0:40  0.1 NaN  NaN  NaN          0.1
5   12/03/2017 0:50  0.6 NaN  NaN  0.5          0.5
6   12/03/2017 1:00  0.4 NaN  0.3  NaN          0.3
7   12/03/2017 1:10  0.3 NaN  NaN  0.2          0.2
8   12/03/2017 1:20  0.9 NaN  NaN  NaN          0.8
9   12/03/2017 1:30  0.9 NaN  NaN  NaN          0.8
10  12/03/2017 1:40  0.0 NaN  NaN  NaN          0.9
```

EDIT:

Thank you [shivsn](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44907160/update-single-column-based-on-multiple-priority-columns/44907396?noredirect=1#comment76793334_44907396) for comments.

If have `Nan` (string values) in `DataFrame` what are not `NaN`s (missing values) or empty string values is necessary first [`replace`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.replace.html):

```
updated_col =  'Updated Col'
cols = ['1','2','3','4'] + ['Updated Col']
d = {'Nan':np.nan, '': np.nan}
df = df.replace(d)
df[updated_col] = df[cols].ffill(axis=1)[updated_col]
print (df)
               Date    1   2    3    4 Updated Col
0   12/03/2017 0:00  0.4 NaN  NaN  NaN         0.9
1   12/03/2017 0:10  0.4 NaN  NaN  NaN         0.1
2   12/03/2017 0:20  0.4 NaN  NaN  NaN         0.6
3   12/03/2017 0:30  0.9 NaN  0.7  NaN         0.7
4   12/03/2017 0:40  0.1 NaN  NaN  NaN         0.1
5   12/03/2017 0:50  0.6 NaN  NaN  0.5         0.5
6   12/03/2017 1:00  0.4 NaN  0.3  NaN         0.3
7   12/03/2017 1:10  0.3 NaN  NaN  0.2         0.2
8   12/03/2017 1:20  0.9 NaN  NaN  NaN         0.8
9   12/03/2017 1:30  0.9 NaN  NaN  NaN         0.8
10  12/03/2017 1:40  0.0 NaN  NaN  NaN         0.9
```

Comment: shift the value `0.7` in column `3` to `2` as in op's `df` then applying your solution doesn't give the expected result. I think its because it contains `NaN` at the start and end, so `ffill` would not work.

Comment: Hmm, if column 4 is high priority and column 1 low priority it should workk perfectly.

Comment: yes but it is giving `nan` in rows `3,4,5,6,7 ` try the solution on the op's df, only value 0.7 should be in column `2` rather than `3`. Try it maybe you will understand me if i'am not clear.

Comment: I dont understand, sorry. It doesnt give nans in columns 3-7, because ffill and if values in one row always last value is with higher priority. My solution works with OP data perfectly. Or something missing? Can you explain more? Thanks.

Comment: Check [this](http://imgur.com/t6WtLmx) it may help you understand what I'am saying.

Comment: Oooo, thank you. I think it is only typo of sample data, no Nan but NaN.

Comment: And I like your comments, so +30 ;)

Comment: Thank you the answer should have been accepted long ago.I always see your answers and try to learn from them.

Comment: Thanks for the help all - looks like i was overthinking this! Jezrael, I would never have thought of fillna with axis =1 so thanks for that, works perfectly.

Comment: Apologies regarding the NaNs, i should have been more explicit. I meant to state that you should assume any blank space was NaN (np.nan) in the frame. Thanks.